# What is the order of p-values in the Matlab tstat data structure?

Tags: matlab

I used the following scripts to compute the p-values for t-test:

```
stats = regstats(Ratio,Delay,'quadratic');
stats.tstat.pval;
```

It shows a column of 3 numbers,

e.g.

```
0.0001
0.0002
0.0003
```

they should be corresponding to the coefficients:

```
y = ax^2 + bx + c
```

Then which is corresponding to which?

Comment: @Macduff You mean 0.0001 is for c, right?

Comment: yes, and this order is shared by all the statistical tools I know.

Comment: confirmed by http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/f-statistic-and-t-statistic.html#bty1m3o-1